What is the difference between 자세하다 and 구체적이다?
I came across these two words, and they both seem to mean "to be detailed/ specific". Apart from the fact that 구체적이다 is derived from 구체적, which is a noun, where as 자세하다 is a descriptive verb, is there any difference in their meanings?

구체적 usually means "concrete," and is the opposite of 추상적 "abstract": that is, it is something that can be described in concrete terms and examples.  E.g.,

이 정책의 구체적인 목표는 무엇입니까? = What is the concrete objective of this policy?

In many cases, it can be also understood as "detailed": when you explain something using concrete terms, you are also explaining it in detail.  But the primary meaning is subtly different.  You can even combine them:

이 정책의 구체적인 목표를 자세히 설명해 주세요. = Please explain, in detail, the concrete objective of this policy.

